# wp_nav_menu() doesn't assign proper class to elements and it forces wrapping the ul element

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, menuitem

I'm having trouble with `wp_nav_menu` function. I want the menu to have no `div` wrapper;
have the class `sf-menu right` for `ul` element of the menu and `li` elements not have any classes. I've tried many combinations, but hasn't gave me the proper result.

my current `wp_nav_menu` function:

```
    <div class="col-md-11">
        <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
            'container'       => false,
            'menu_class'      => 'sf-menu right',

        )); ?>
    </div>
```

How can I achieve my goal result?

**EDIT**

my result after trying :

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
            'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
            'container'       => '',
            'items_wrap' => '<ul class="sf-menu right"><li></li>%3$s</ul>' )
    ); ?>
</div>
```

**RESULT :**

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item page-item-20"><a href="http://localhost/oranet/website-optimization/">بهینه سازی وبسایت</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-26"><a href="http://localhost/oranet/contact-oranet/">تماس با ما</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-18 page_item_has_children"><a href="http://localhost/oranet/web-design/">طراحی سایت</a>
                <ul class="children">
                    <li class="page_item page-item-28"><a href="http://localhost/oranet/web-design/portfolio/">نمونه کارها</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-22"><a href="http://localhost/oranet/e-commerce/">فروشگاه اینترنتی</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item page-item-24"><a href="http://localhost/oranet/articles/">مقالات</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this following code

```
<div class="col-md-11">
    <?php wp_nav_menu(array(
        'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
        'container'       => '',
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="sf-menu right"><li></li>%3$s</ul>' )
    )); ?>
</div>
```